# Canvas to base64 does not work when drawing image from file

Tags: javascript, php, html5-canvas

I am drawing image from file to a HTML5 canvas. The image draws fine on canvas. When I send this to PHP to save base64 string to server I always get empty image... Empty image is only when I draw image to canvas, if I draw something like the image will save as being drawn.

For example this will be submitted to PHP and the image will be saved to disk as drawn...

```
var canvas = $("canvas")[0];
var context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(170, 80);
context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
context.closePath();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
context.fill();
context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
context.stroke();
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "profile_pic_data").val(dataURL);
$("form").append($(input));
```

This one won't. This code allows user to browse for image file and crop it. The cropped image then gets drawn to canvas, which works fine, but when I send this to PHP (same way as above) I always get blank image (base64 string is also always same whatever image I select and draw)? I tried virtually everything and I have no clues where I am doing it wrong...

```
function loadImageFile() {
    if (document.getElementById("uploadfile").files.length === 0) return;
    var e = document.getElementById("uploadfile").files[0];
    if (!rFilter.test(e.type)) {
        return
    }
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(e)
}
var one = new CROP;
$("body").on("click", ".newupload", function () {
    $(".uploadfile").click()
});
$("body").change(".uploadfile", function () {
    loadImageFile();
    $(".uploadfile").wrap("<form>").closest("form").get(0).reset();
    $(".uploadfile").unwrap()
});
oFReader = new FileReader, rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;
oFReader.onload = function (e) {
    $(".profile-pic").html('<div class="default"><div class="cropMain"></div><div class="cropSlider"></div></div>');
    one = new CROP;
    one.init(".default");
    one.loadImg(e.target.result);
}
$('#form_profile').submit(function(e) {
    var canvas = $("canvas")[0];
    var e = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        t = new Image,
        n = coordinates(one).w,
        r = coordinates(one).h,
        i = coordinates(one).x,
        s = coordinates(one).y,
        o = 240,
        u = 240;
    t.src = coordinates(one).image;
    t.onload = function () {
        e.drawImage(t, i, s, n, r, 0, 0, o, u);
    }

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "profile_pic_data").val(dataURL);
    $(this).append($(input));
});
```

This is my PHP, which should work:

```
$upload_dir = DOCROOT.'assets/img/profile-pics/';
$img = $_POST['profile_pic_data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir.$this->current_user->id.'.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Comment: Just wondering - what do you expect `$("body").change(".uploadfile", function () {` to do?

Comment: This is just a listener on file input `<input id="uploadfile" class="uploadfile" name="profile_pic" type="file">` which calls loadImageFile() function when a file gets selected by user which loads and validates file...

Comment: Well it's not targeting that class, if that's what you're thinking. `.change()` doesn't expect a selector in the paramters like `.on()` might: http://api.jquery.com/change/ - I don't think this is the source of your problem, I'm just saying

Comment: It is, the .change is firing fine... This works and it's not the source of my problem... It's just that data I get from canvas is always the same, blank 240x240 PNG image and I don't know why?!

Comment: I know it is, but it's not firing **only** for elements with the class "uploadfile" - it's firing for any element that triggers a `change` event. That first parameter to `change` (".uploadfile") is being used as event data that you can grab in the handler. It's not being used as a selector. I was just pointing out that the handler isn't specifically targeting `.uploadfile`, it's targeting anything

Comment: Also, I think the problem is the asynchronous nature of `t.onload`. The `e.drawImage(t, i, s, n, r, 0, 0, o, u);` is executing **after** the `submit` handler completes, so the image isn't drawn on the canvas. You'll have to wait for the image to load so it can be drawn on the canvas before submitting the form. That might mean canceling the current form submit event, waiting for the image to load and drawing on the canvas then appending the input to another form and submitting that one.

Comment: @Ian you were right! I have managed to get it work by submitting the form after the t.onload is finished drawing image...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own solution based on comment from @Ian. The form was submitting empty canvas, because it was submitting before then Image.onload was finished drawing on canvas.

Change was needed to submit form after Image.onload is complete. Here is the updated code:

```
$('#btn-profile-update').click(function(e) {
    if($('.crop-img').length)
    {
        $("canvas").remove();
        $('#form_profile').after('<canvas id="profile-pic-canvas" width="240" height="240" id="canvas"/>');
        var canvas = $("canvas")[0];
        var e = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            t = new Image,
            n = coordinates(one).w,
            r = coordinates(one).h,
            i = coordinates(one).x,
            s = coordinates(one).y,
            o = 240,
            u = 240;
        t.src = coordinates(one).image;
        t.onload = function () {
            e.drawImage(t, i, s, n, r, 0, 0, o, u);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "profile_pic_data").val(dataURL);
            $('#form_profile').append($(input));
            $('#form_profile').submit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $('#form_profile').submit();
    }
});
```